# Properties of cell editor in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

How to make excel cell editor property as text by default in excel.

Actually cell property is general.How can i make that as text in excel

(Right click on excel cell editor

click on format cell

In number tab it highlight general only

How can i change general to text default)

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (Select all),
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (Format Cells),
3. Select **Text** from the **Category** column and press **OK**.

But if you set all cells to Text formatting you lose the ability to enter formulas, in which case you might as well be using a table in Microsoft Word.

Comment: before modifying the cell its ok but after modifying cells and i change property then its not working.so by default i have to change one time and then changes will occur every time when ever iam using excel

Answer (score 1):

Here're the [official Microsoft instructions on how to start Excel with a specific workbook template](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/customize-how-excel-starts-HP005199391.aspx). You need to review the last section called "Save workbook settings you want to use every time you start Excel with a workbook template (book.xlt)".

Use Mike Fitzpatrick's instructions to create the styling template.

Comment: You could also change Personal.XLSX because Excel will use it by default for any new workbook

Comment: The question is about Excel 2003.

Comment: Damn! but my comment is still worth it with the `Personal.xls`